# Facebook api ui - displaying gibrish for none English text

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am using Phonegap plugin: facebookConnect.showDialog
It calls FB.ui
I am trying to make it show a dialog with hebrew message.
I would rather put the message in the input textbox, but I tink it is impossible.
What I see is gibrish text, and I don't see the link.

![enter image description here][1]

```html
 facebookConnectPlugin.showDialog( 
    {
        method: "feed",
        picture:'http://www.mobile-gap.com/bible/icons/'+app_type+'/96.png',
        caption: title,
        link: url,
        description: message
    },
    post_message_sccess,  post_message_fail
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the solution (after many wasted hours).
You need to add the charset="utf-8" to the  of the html file.

```
<head><meta charset="UTF-8"></head>
```